# problem with grails 6.1.0 and encoding text .gsp

Tags: grails, encoding, utf-8, special-characters, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to configure the encoding of utf8 in grails but not even putting in tomcat 9 the utf8, neither in the .gsp warnings nor in the application.yml, nothing works, I put Spanish character "ñ" and when I send it from the gsp to the controller it is already changed as "Ã±" they say it's for another ISO-8859-1 encoding but I don't know how to fix it and I've been several days, is it still a bug? In old versions there was, does anyone know anything or can you recommend me a solution?

I would like to find a solution to the problem of the utf8 coding of grails